# git: Why am I ahead of origin/master with X commits after I do 'git push'?

Tags: git, commit, remote-branch

I am using a bare git repository on a server for backup, and push local changes there with 'git push' after doing 'git commit' locally.

'git status' tells me

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by X commits.
```

If I modify a file, and then do another commit followed by a push, git tells me that my branch is ahead by X+1 commits. 'git remote show origin' shows me that both fetch and pull URLs are the same as I supply as argument to push.

I have verified that my changes do indeed get pushed to the server repository (by pulling into a different location and checking the contents).

What am I doing wrong here?

PS: I am aware that there are several related questions here on SO, but I could not find the answer to my specific issue in any of those. Please point me in the right direction if I'm wrong in that regard.

Comment: I have no answer for you but I want you to know you're not alone! I sometimes see this message, and if I do a pull/push, even though nothing seems to be transferred, this goes away.

Comment: have you tried to run 'git fetch origin' after pushing ? Maybe the remote branch doesn't get updated after the push.

Comment: @François, indeed, same as for pushing, it's the reference name that matters (to get it updated).

Comment: @François is right.  Do a 'git fetch origin' to update tracking info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're pushing to the URL directly. Try `git push origin`, this will update the references for `origin` (in principle, you can have the same URLs twice with the same reference name: the message refers to the reference name).

Comment: Thank you, that took care of it!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you'll run into this even though you actually don't have local commits. If you're stuck, and a

```
git pull origin [branch]
```

doesn't help you out, simply try

```
git pull origin and git pull
```

These commands should set your repo straight and clear up your issue of being ahead of origin/master by X commits.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that updating your tracking information of "origin" works as well.

Try:

```
git fetch origin
```